# speed word problem

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I've got this question:
) 
A 
ladder 
15ft 
long 
leans 
against 
a vertical 
wall. 
If 
the 
top 
slides 
down 
at 
2ft 
per 
second, 
how 
fast 
along 
the 
ground 
is 
the 
base 
moving 
when 
it 
is 
5ft 
from 
the 
wall?

.....

I'm not entirely sure how to approach this. the only thing I can work out is that since the top is sliding at 2ft per second, then the bottom must be too. any solutions?

thanks

Comment: Related: [knowing sliding velocity of bottom of wall, asking for velocity of top of ladder](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/618017/the-speed-of-the-top-of-a-sliding-ladder), [another example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1189496/differential-calculus), [abstract duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/847114/understanding-related-rates-ladder-problem).

Answer (score 1):

Let $h(t)$ be the height of the top at time $t$ and $b(t)$ be the position of the base at time $t$. At the beginning we have $h(0) = 15,\ b(0) = 0$. Also $t$ is in second. Moreover you know that $h'(t) = -2$.

Clearly for any $t$, we must have $b(t)^2 + h(t)^2 = 15^2$.
Talking the derivative (w.r.t $t$) of this expression gives:
$$
2b'(t)b(t) + 2h'(t)h(t) = 0
$$
Now you can rearrange it to extract $b'(t)$ knowing that $b(t) = 5$ and using pythagorian relation for $h(t)$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

By Pythagoras's theorem,
$l^2 = h^2 + b^2$

Differentiating with respect to t, we get
$2l\frac{dl}{dt}=2h\frac{dh}{dt} + 2b\frac{db}{dt}$

Since the length of the ladder is constant. Hence, $\frac{dl}{dt}= 0.$
Also h = 12 feets.

Hence, $\frac{db}{dt} = -\frac{2*h*\frac{dh}{dt}}{\frac{db}{dt}} = \frac{2*12*2}{2*5} = -4.8 ft/s $

[The minus sign denotes that the end of the ladder touching the surface is sliding away from the wall.]